# Splitting lists inside list haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Hi I need to split list by an argument in Haskell. I found function like this

```
group :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
group _ [] = []
group n l
  | n > 0 = (take n l) : (group n (drop n l))
  | otherwise = error "Negative n"
```

But what if lists that I want to divide are contained by another list?

For example

```
group 3 [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,6,8,10,12]]
```

should return

```
[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,4,6],[8,10,12]]]
```

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Just do `map` over the elements (lists) of that list:

```
grouplists :: [[a]] -> Int -> [[[a]]]
grouplists input n = map (group n) input
```

Comment: I have trouble implementing that because of type errors

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
group n = map (toList . splitAt n)
  where
    toList (x,y) = [x,y]
```

**UPDATE**
Given that the specification involves repeated taking and dropping here's how I would do it:

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

group :: Int -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
group n = map (unfoldr split)
  where
    split = (\s -> listToMaybe (fst s) >> Just s) . splitAt n
```

You'll notice that inside here is also the definition of what *you* have implemented as `group`. It is `unfoldr split`.

Comment: This function only takes n of elements to separate list not every n elements. Like this:  [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8,9]]] when it should be [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]]

Comment: Your test case does not make that clear... (please add this test case to your answer, I will update my answer).